How to refer other transactions (using `transaction.addLink`)?
I am trying to link two transactions happening across services. I have the traceparent string for transaction txnA in service-a, in service-b I have an ongoing transaction txnB where I would like to link txnA such that both appear in the kibana view. According to NodeJS agent docs txnB.addLink({ context: txnATraceparent }) should work.
After doing the same I can't see any child transaction in txnA or any additional transactions in txnA parent.
PS: I am using elastic-apm-node package for NodeJS Agent and this is my init code:
    const apm = require('elastic-apm-node').start({
        serviceName: 'server-2',
        serverUrl: apmConfig.serverUrl,
        distributedTracingOrigins: [apmConfig.serverUrl],
        environment: apmConfig.environment,
        active: !apmConfig.disableTracing,
    });
    console.log("APM Tracer initialized")

